# creating a curved box-shadow with CSS3

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a curved box-shadow with CSS3? Below is an image of what I am asking about:

[image]

Comment: That is not possible with just one element. You'll have to use a few extra divs with shadows and rotation to create the effect you're after, but it would be easier with a bg image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyle Sevenoaks is right but try using gradients:

```
.rad_gra{
background:-moz-radial-gradient(center, #fff, #adf);
background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, #fff, #adf);
background:-ms-radial-gradient(center, #fff, #adf);
background:radial-gradient(center, #fff, #adf);
}

.lin_gra{
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #adf);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #adf);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #adf);
background:linear-gradient(top, #fff, #adf); /* W3C Standard */
}
```

Comment: this are not the gradients you need .. just a example how it works